# I want to convert a dictionary to pandas dataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-analysis

```
di={'ind': 1, 'age': 59, 'bp': 70, 'sg': 1.01, 'al': 1.0, 'su': 3.0, 'rbc': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0, 'pcc': 0.0, 'ba': 0.0, 'bgr': 424.0, 'bu': 55.0, 'sc': 1.7, 'sod': 138.0, 'pot': 4.5, 'hemo': 12.0, 'pcv': 37.0, 'wbcc': 10200.0, 'rbcc': 4.1, 'htn': 1.0, 'dm': 1.0, 'cad': 1.0, 'appet': 1.0, 'pe': 0.0, 'ane': 1.0}
```

I'm having this dictionary, and I want to convert this to a pandas dataframe with `'ind': 1` as the index, 24 columns and 1 row.

These are the names of each column that I want to have in my df:-

```
d=['age', 'bp', 'sg','al', 'su', 'rbc', 'pc', 'pcc', 'ba', 'bgr', 'bu', 'sc', 'sod', 'pot', 'hemo', 'pcv', 'wbcc', 'rbcc', 'htn', 'dm','cad', 'appet', 'pe', 'ane']
```

Please guide me with it. I tried the method `pd.DataFrame(di.items(), columns=d)` but it returned a df with 1 column and 24 rows, I wan the reciprocal of it i.e. 24 columns and 1 row.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
di={'ind': 1, 'age': 59, 'bp': 70, 'sg': 1.01, 'al': 1.0, 'su': 3.0, 'rbc': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0, 'pcc': 0.0, 'ba': 0.0, 'bgr': 424.0, 'bu': 55.0, 'sc': 1.7, 'sod': 138.0, 'pot': 4.5, 'hemo': 12.0, 'pcv': 37.0, 'wbcc': 10200.0, 'rbcc': 4.1, 'htn': 1.0, 'dm': 1.0, 'cad': 1.0, 'appet': 1.0, 'pe': 0.0, 'ane': 1.0}

print( pd.DataFrame([di]).set_index('ind') )
```

Prints:

```
     age  bp    sg   al   su  rbc   pc  pcc   ba    bgr    bu   sc    sod  pot  hemo   pcv     wbcc  rbcc  htn   dm  cad  appet   pe  ane
ind                                                                                                                                      
1     59  70  1.01  1.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  424.0  55.0  1.7  138.0  4.5  12.0  37.0  10200.0   4.1  1.0  1.0  1.0    1.0  0.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df = pd.Series(di).to_frame(0).T.set_index('ind')
```